# Invalid Option: module is not a valid top-level option

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

There is an error when I used the `babel-loader`. I already omitted all the code unrelated to the error. What has gone wrong?

```
module.exports = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.[jt]s$/,
                use: [
                    'babel-loader'
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/src/index.ts: Invalid Option: module is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'modules'? (While processing: "/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
    at validateTopLevelOptions (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:35:13)
    at normalizeOptions (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:176:3)
    at /Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:239:37
    at /Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
    at /Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:199:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:26:3)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/gensync/index.js:254:32)
    at evaluateAsync (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/gensync/index.js:284:5)
    at Function.errback (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/gensync/index.js:108:7)
    at errback (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:70:18)
    at async (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/gensync/index.js:183:31)
    at onFirstPause (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/gensync/index.js:209:13)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at cachedFunction (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:68:46)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadPresetDescriptor (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:292:43)
    at loadPresetDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
    at recurseDescriptors (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:107:30)
    at recurseDescriptors.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadFullConfig (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:142:6)
    at loadFullConfig.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.transform (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:25:45)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/gensync/index.js:262:25)
    at /Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/gensync/index.js:266:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/gensync/index.js:216:11)
    at /Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/gensync/index.js:184:28
    at /Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:72:7
    at /Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/gensync/index.js:108:33
    at step (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/gensync/index.js:280:14)
    at /Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/gensync/index.js:266:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (/Users/eterna/workspaces/experiments/neoteric/node_modules/gensync/index.js:216:11)
```

package.json

```
"babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
"webpack": "^4.44.2",
"webpack-merge": "^5.1.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem showed up in ~/project, but I had also ~/node_modules with obsoleted version of @babel/preset-env